# CSS Selector for selecting a column in same row of html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a question about how to update column in the same row using css class selector. below is the example scenario.

| Item | Price | Discount <User Input> | Final Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mobile | 500 | 10 | 450 |
| Laptop | 1000 | 20 | 800 |

From the above table, discount column has text fields at each row. When user enters the discount percentage, the final price of that row much be updated accordingly.

assume that column Final Price has class attribute(.final-price).

Please let me know the css selector for this scenario so that I can use it in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Sri

I have tried:

I tried using siblings() function from css, however it ended up using number, siblings()[3]. Somehow, I need to make this dynamically (not numbering).

Comment: the HTML would help if you want help with it - by the way, DOM elements have a property `.nextElementSibling` which may be of use to your problem

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").find("td.final-price")` or `$(this).closest("tr").find("td.final-price > input")`  where `this` would be the input and the code would be in the input's `input` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You have this structure:

```
<tr>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="final-price">450</td>
</tr>
```

There is no selector that goes up the CSS and selects an element from another parent. So you need to do this in two steps:

1. Leave $input and get to $tr (which is the first common parent element)
2. From $tr search for ".final-price"

```js
const $table = $("table")

$table.on("input", event => {
  const $input = $(event.target),
        $tdFinalPrice = $input.closest("tr").find(".final-price")
  $tdFinalPrice.css("background-color", "red")
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, input {
  padding: 10px;

  /* font */
  color: #000;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 19px;
}

tr {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-style: solid;
}

th {
  background-color: #eee;
}

th,
td {
  position: relative;
    width: calc(100% / 4);
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-style: solid;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Final Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="final-price">450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laptop</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
        <td class="final-price">800</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```